# Sample applications for practicing API Testing

Tags: api-testing

I am looking for some sample (ideally open source applications) that I could use to start practicing API testing. I am mainly interested in applications developed with .NET.

Any ideas or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: [You can use Google to search for that](https://www.google.com/search?q=dot+net+open+source#q=dot+net+open+source+projects).

Comment: Hi everyone. Thanks for your comments and feedback. I do respect the fact that Stack Overflow has its own rules for assessing the contents of the questions posted. However, it is really disencouraging to see questions put on hold (and I can see that happening for many questions and being triggered by the same old users) or see comments like "you can search on google". Yes, I can search on Google for everything but then there is no meaning in using Stack Overflow.  Actually, I will be only searching on Google from now on!

Comment: Hi tasos. There's a discussion going on about why this question was closed. Note that user246, who pointed you toward Google, did not vote to close your question. In other words, it isn't the fact that you can find it on Google that makes it closed. Feel free to read my [full comments here](http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/a/432/65), and don't be shy about joining the discussion! Thanks

Comment: Hi corsiKa. Thanks for the detailed and well explained comments. What would have been in your opinion the best way to re-phrase the question so as to fit a format that would be acceptable to Stack Overflow? For example is the question "What steps should I follow to learn API testing for .NET applications" any closer to an acceptable format? Or it would be better to post questions for the actual API testing itself? As soon as there is creative feedback like yours provided, it is easier to learn how to post quality questions in Stack Overflow and keep the users of the forum engaged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have **Web API Samples** from ASP.NET that you can learn on.

[ASP.NET Web API Samples](https://www.asp.net/aspnet/samples/aspnet-web-api)

The following code samples, which use the **Google APIs Client Library for .NET**, are available for the YouTube Data API.
For example the first code sample below calls the API's playlistItems.list method to retrieve a list of videos uploaded to the channel associated with the request.

[.NET Code Samples - YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet)

Maybe this would be helpful too while learning:
[Let's Build an API Checking Framework](https://dojo.ministryoftesting.com/series/let-s-build-an-api-checking-framework-mark-winteringham)